How to measure capacitance of a single surface mount foil capacitor?
I broke a surface mount capacitor off in my LED light for my truck. How do I measure capacitance on the twin sister capacitor on the board?
Well I've been looking it up myself too and I need a better meter that has capacitance selection for one thing.
I broke capacitor C3 while I was trying to fix the wiring which there jet melted in and it had to open in it I believe it's the same size as C2 I need to measure that find one somewhere.


You can buy a meter and remove the cap to measure it. But then what? You don't know if the missing capacitor had same capacitance or not. Even if it had the same capacitance, you still don't know the other parameters of the capacitor. Such as voltage rating, dielectric type, temperature range, or any rating for automotive or fail-safe usage. So what is the point of measuring some other cap? It's also not a foil capacitor if it looked like the other capacitors. It was a multilayer ceramic capacitor.

To measure capacitance you typically have to remove the part from the circuit (unsolder it- or perhaps cut one of the traces) and use a capacitance meter.
That's the answer to your question.
As far as your problem goes- a photo of the capacitor and the surrounding circuitry and we might be able to suggest something that will typically work. "Foil" does not suggest a particular type of SMT capacitor to me.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/725262/417595
